# Python Function that returns None

Tags: python

I don't understand, why is `foo()` returning None?

```
def foo(a,b):
    if a+b == 12:
        return True
print(foo(7,5)) # Works fine
print(foo(1,3)) # prints None
```

Comment: Neither `7+4` nor `1+3` is equal to `12`.

Comment: What do you want to print?

Comment: Because you didn't handle the `else`.

Comment: Because 1+3 isn’t 12.

Comment: python functions always return something. When you don't explicitly return a value, they will return a None implicitly.

Comment: What did you expect it to return?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You should return another bool if `a+b` is not 12

```
def foo(a,b):
    if a+b == 12:
        return True
    else:
        return False
answer1 = foo(1,3)
answer2 = foo(7,5)
if answer1:
    print "1 + 3 = 12"
if answer2:
    print "7 + 5 = 12"
```

`foo()` will return `True` if `a+b` == 12, if not should return `False`

Comment: Please don’t make a boolean test to decide which boolean to return. Directly return the test results.

Comment: `1plus3is12` and `7plus5is12` are not valid variable names.